# Nested UIScrollViews - can't scroll to new photo after zooming

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, scroll, zooming

This behavior is in Apple's PhotoScroller example app (I just tested the version they released for `iOS 6`), and even in the `iOS 5`/`iOS 6` default "Photo" app. (I didn't test any other versions.)

When I zoom into a photo and then try to swipe it off the screen to the left (so that the next photo should come in from the right), something strange happens: As I move my finger the current photo moves in the same direction, but only with about half the speed. When I lift up my finger, the current photo scrolls back so that the edge of the photo and the screen align. The next time I try to swipe, it works as expected: the current photo moves off the screen and the next one comes in.

Is there something I can do to make it change to the next photo on the first try? My app is based on the PhotoScroller example.

[Some information for those not familiar with the PhotoScroller example app: There is one `UIScrollView` that handles swiping betweeen different pages, and for every page, there is one to zoom into the photo on that page.]

I've just compared this behavior to how it is in iBooks, and there it is like I want it in my app too, I can swipe to the next page immediately, even if I just zoomed into the previous page.

Any feedback appreciated!

Comment: Any luck with figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set zoomable scroll view property "bounces" to NO:

```
zoomableScrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

first load the same image that you need to scroll in code

UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.jpg"];

then match frame size of the UIImageView that you scrolling with size of the image in code

self.UIImageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.UIImageView.frame.origin.x, self.UIImageView.frame.origin.y, yourImage.size.width, yourImage.size.width) ;

best load this code in ViewDidLoad.